# ContextFlyout and SwipeControl conflict

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

I have a `ListView`, whose `ItemTemplate` has a `SwipeControl` and a `ContextFlyout`.

However, when I long press (I am not using mouse just my finger) the `PlaylistControlItem`, the `LeftItems` of `SwipeControl` shows up instead of the `ContextFlyout`.

How should I make the `ContextFlyout` show up instead?

Below is my `ListView`:

```
<ListView
    SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Music">
            <SwipeControl Loaded="SwipeControl_Loaded">
                <SwipeControl.LeftItems>
                    <SwipeItems Mode="Reveal">
                        <SwipeItem Text="Favorite">
                        </SwipeItem>
                    </SwipeItems>
                </SwipeControl.LeftItems>
                <SwipeControl.RightItems>
                    <SwipeItems Mode="Execute">
                        <SwipeItem Text="Remove">
                        </SwipeItem>
                    </SwipeItems>
                </SwipeControl.RightItems>
                <local:PlaylistControlItem DataContext="{x:Bind}" ShowAlbumText="{Binding ElementName=PlaylistController, Path=ShowAlbumText}">
                    <local:PlaylistControlItem.ContextFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyout Opening="OpenMusicMenuFlyout" />
                    </local:PlaylistControlItem.ContextFlyout>
                </local:PlaylistControlItem>
            </SwipeControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

More source code [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/PlaylistControl.xaml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing optimizations for different modes of operation is a great idea, but it also needs to follow some design principles.

But it should be noted that both `ContextFlyout` and `SwipeControl` have their own internal operation logic, such as `SwipeControl` is a finger swipe, `ContextFlyout` is a right click or long press. You can't modify this.

You can try to bind `ContextFlyout` to a higher level, which might help. Like this:

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <UserControl>
        <UserControl.ContextFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout Opening="OpenMusicMenuFlyout" />
        </UserControl.ContextFlyout>
        <SwipeControl>
            <SwipeControl.LeftItems>
                <SwipeItems Mode="Reveal">
                    <SwipeItem Text="Favorite">
                    </SwipeItem>
                </SwipeItems>
            </SwipeControl.LeftItems>
            <SwipeControl.RightItems>
                <SwipeItems Mode="Execute">
                    <SwipeItem Text="Remove">
                    </SwipeItem>
                </SwipeItems>
            </SwipeControl.RightItems>
            <local:PlaylistControlItem DataContext="{x:Bind}" ShowAlbumText="{Binding ElementName=PlaylistController, Path=ShowAlbumText}">
            </local:PlaylistControlItem>
        </SwipeControl>
    </UserControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

But from a user experience perspective, I don't recommend mixing `ContextFlyout` and `SwipeControl`. They are all implicit operations, that means, there is no obvious hint on the UI to tell the user to do so.

What you are doing is a playlist. My suggestion is to add a `MoreButton` to the end of the `PlaylistControlItem`. This is an obvious hint. After clicking, you can display `Flyout` and use it instead of the implicit `ContextFlyout`.

If you still intend to call `ContextFlyout` with a long press, consider making a clear hint on the UI to tell the user "can do this".

In addition, some of the same program processing logic may be used to optimize the experience for different devices. UWP has a design pattern built specifically for this purpose. You can refer to [Commanding in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps using StandardUICommand, XamlUICommand, and ICommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/commanding) to optimize your code and build a great experience across devices

---

**Update**

I tested your code and checked the cause of the problem. You omit a `ListView.CanDragItems` property when setting the `AllowReorder` property.

Try this:

```cs
public bool AllowReorder
{
    get => SongsListView.CanReorderItems;
    set
    {
        SongsListView.CanReorderItems = SongsListView.AllowDrop = SongsListView.CanDragItems = SongsListView.CanDrag = value;
    }
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded your code and tested it. I am using an emulator (This is the test device that comes with Visual Studio and can be used to simulate touch screen) . It works fine in the case of a simulated touch screen. As long as I don't move my finger, `SwipeControl` does not appear. If you have problems with the actual device, this may be related to the touch screen.

Comment: I just noticed that when property `AllowReorder=true` it works and when `false` it fails. How can I make it work when `AllowReorder=false`? The property is defined [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/PlaylistControl.xaml.cs). With it being true you can use drag and drop to reorder the `ListView` otherwise you can neither drag and drop nor reorder. It is only true when you are in the Now Playing Page. Could you test on pages be like My Favorite Page?